# jQuery interval won't restart after hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, setinterval

After calling a PHP function, which generates the HTML,
I call the function below for the specific slider id.
That works fine, hover pauses the slideshow, also ok.
But when I am hovering out of the section, firebug gives the following error:
TypeError: o.handler.apply is not a function 
And the slideshow won't continue.
Thanks in advance.

```
function CallSlider(sliderid){
var $slider = $('#'+sliderid);
var $slide = 'li';
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 2000; // 4 seconds

function slides(){
return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

$('#'+sliderid).hover(function() {
clearInterval(sliderid);

}, sliderid = setInterval(

function(){
  var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();
//alert('test');
  slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
  slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

  if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

  slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
  slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
}
, $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
)
);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that error is related to the fact that `hover()` expects parameters to be functions.

> Type: Function() - A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters/leaves the element.
>   http://api.jquery.com/hover/

I suggest putting your "hover off" code in its own function, like so:

```
$('#'+sliderid).hover(
  function() {
    // hover over
    clearInterval(sliderid);
  },
  function () {
    // hover off
    sliderid = setInterval(...);
  }
);
```

### EDIT:

Here's an example, based on the code you provided, of how to keep things flexible (i.e. for dynamic lists).

```
var slide = 'li';
var transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var time_between_slides = 2000; // 4 seconds


function startCycle($slider, $slides) {
    return setInterval(
        function () {

            var $thisslide=jQuery(slide+'.active',$slider);
            var $nextslide=($thisslide.next(slide).length?$thisslide.next(slide):$slides.eq(0));
            $thisslide.removeClass('active').fadeOut(transition_time);
            $nextslide.fadeIn(transition_time).addClass('active');

        }, transition_time + time_between_slides
    );
}

jQuery('ul.slider').each(function () {

    var sliderid;

    var $slider = jQuery(this);
    var $slides = $slider.find(slide);

    $slides.fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    $slides.first().addClass('active').fadeIn(transition_time);

    $slider.hover(
        function () {
            // hover over
            clearInterval(this.sliderid);
        },
        function () {
            // hover off
            this.sliderid = startCycle($slider, $slides);
        }
    );

    this.sliderid = startCycle($slider, $slides);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk74V/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that worked, but...the slider won't start now at pageload.?

Comment: Are you initializing the `startInterval()` on page load? Otherwise it will only start after you hover off the element. Here's my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/aJVJA/

Comment: That's great code and it works but it avoids me to keep the function dynamic. Because of the static #test in your fiddle. I would like to call this slider multiple times with only the use of 1 function.

Comment: My example is not intended as a replacement for your code. It's only an example of the proper `hover()` syntax. You can keep your code dynamic. Just modify the way you call `setInterval` by placing it inside an anonymous function like you did for `clearInterval(sliderid)`. If you can build a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), I'll attempt to edit it for you.

Comment: ok: http://jsfiddle.net/gk74V/ Succes! Both sliders must start onpage load, pause on hover and contine on hoverout. All seperately.